# Creating BLOBs with EclipseLink

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I'm trying to switch from Hibernate to EclipseLink. Now I'm facing the problem of creating BLOBs. With Hibernate I solved it this way:

```
import org.hibernate.LobHelper;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;

...
  public Blob createBlob(InputStream inputStream, long length)
  {
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    LobHelper lobHelper = session.getLobHelper();
    Blob blob = lobHelper.createBlob(inputStream, length);
    return blob;
  }
```

Any hints how I can do this with EclipseLink? (I'm on an Oracle DB).

Jonny